# PowerBI "contains" slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with a column that is a semi-colon delimited list of tags for each row. I would like to create a slicer that allows me to do a "contains" type slice on the tags column.

Example record:

```
Title       | Tags
foobar      | thingA; thingB
barfoo      | thingC; thingA; otherThing
```

Slicer

```
thingA |  thingB | thingC
```

Selecting "thingA" should result in both rows being displayed.

I can see how to make a new query to populate the values of the slicer with a distinct action, but now how to create a relationship back to the original table to allow me to slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use a 2nd unpivoted version of your records table.

**Step 1: Create an Unpivoted Records Table**

You can unpivot your tags using the Query Editor.

1. **Split Column by Delimiter** on the Transform toolbar (specifically, split the tags column by a delimiter of ";").
2. Select the multiple Tags columns that result, and choose **Format** > **Trim** to get rid of any superfluous leading or trailing spaces that could mess things up.
3. Select the multiple Tags columns, and choose **Unpivot Columns**.

The result should look something like this:

```
Title  | Tag
-------|-----------
foobar | thingA
foobar | thingB
barfoo | thingC
barfoo | thingA
barfoo | otherThing
```

As long as you reach the final result, it doesn't matter how you get there.

Note, this table is in **addition** to the original tables in your question - it is not a replacement.

**Step 2: Relate Your Tables**

Your *Unpivoted_Records* table should have a relationship to your Slicer table (Single/Many-to-One on Tag) and also to your original Records table (Many-to-One on Title).

The magic ingredient is that the relationship between Unpivoted_Records and Records should have a cross-filter direction of **Both** (double-click on the line to change it).

[image: Image shows the Edit Relationship dialog box, with Cross-Filter direction of both highlighted.]

Both is not the default. What this means is that any filters applied to *Unpivoted_Records* are propagated backwards to the original Records table, filtering that table too.

[image: Picture shows 3 tables: Slicer, Records, and Records_Unpivoted. Slicer & Records are both joined with a line to Records_Unpivoted, but not to each other. The line between Records and Records_Unpvioted has a double arrow.]
*Diagram of how your relationships should look: notice the circled area, indicating the cross-filter direction is "Both"*

**Step 3: Slice Away**

At this point, you can show the Records table in a visual, along with the Slicer table. When you select a value on the slicer, it will filter the Records table. **You do not need to display the unpivoted Records table anywhere, as the slicer selections filter up to your original Records table.**

[image: Picture of a tag slicer, with ThingB selected. The Records table is filtered to foobar.]

**Note on Cross-Filter Directions**

A cross-filter relationship of both can have side-effects that I can't anticipate depending on your actual data model. It shouldn't in this particular example, since Records_Unpivoted only exists for the sole purpose of facilitating the relationship between the slicer table and the Records table. However, if you use a Both relationship in other places and notice oddness going on with slicing & filtering, try turning the relationship back to single to see if the cross-filter direction is the root cause.